# Spring security: Cannot permit access to resource when adding custom filter

Tags: java, spring-security, servlet-filters

I have following configuration for my spring security

```
http
    // if I gonna comment adding filter it's gonna work as expected
    .addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/rest/_health")
            .permitAll()

            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()

            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable();
```

So without custom filter everything works as expected - I have access to /rest/_health and access denied to everything else.

But when I'm adding this filter - matchers don't work and filter works even for 'permitAll' resources.

Code from my filter looks like this:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                     FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    try {
        String token = httpRequest.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new TokenBasedAuthentication(token)
        );

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
        authenticationEntryPoint.commence(httpRequest, httpResponse, ex);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The filter is executed before the checks on the endpoints. In your case the unsuccesful authentication aborts the filter chain and let the access point handle the rest. Whith this you do not allow anonymous access at all. You need to set the Authentication to null to indicate that an anonymous user is accessing the endpoint.

Try the following:

```
    Authentication authentication = null;
    String token = httpRequest.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
    //check if not anonymous and preceed with authentication
    if (token != null && !token.isEmpty()) {
        try {

            authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new TokenBasedAuthentication(token));

        } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
            //illigal access atempt
            authenticationEntryPoint.commence(httpRequest, httpResponse, ex);
        }
    }
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my configuration (that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter), I did it in this way:

```
        http.csrf().disable().
            addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login*", "/logout*").permitAll().anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/secured/index")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true").permitAll()
        .and()
            .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .permitAll();

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/static/**", "/webjars/**", "/error*");
}
```

Maybe not perfect, but it works.

Comment: doesn't work as expected for me, bro
actually, I have almost the same configuration, except login and logout